# Как сделать, чтоб Service ждал пока к нему обратятся?

Tags: java, android

Как правильно сделать такую штуку.

Вот у нас есть сервер, этот сервер время от времени будет подбирать картинку и высылать ее юзеру... Юзер должен получить `notification`.

Я так понимаю это должен работать `service` и получать `token`, но как сделать так, чтоб `service` не постоянно проверял есть ли обновление, а ждал пока, что то не получит от сервера... И как только получает, то сразу запускает `notification`?

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging, нее?

Comment: Копайте в сторону push-ей и работу с GCM, например.  В инете много статей на эту тему. Вот офф статья https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 1):

В итоге все сделал с помощью GCM, Push, Service и BroadcastReceiver.
Статья [здесь.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)